# R - Splitting a column text into 2 columns without delimiter

Tags: r

I need to manipulate the following data frame (data) so that the PATCH_CODE column is split into 2 resulting columns where the 1st column contains the letter of the string and the 2nd column contains the number as in the 2nd example dataframe below.

**EDIT** PATCH_CODE is not always 2 letters, occasional cases have a single letter in which case I need to force a 1 into the resulting code column.

initial data frame: `head(data,4)`

```
PATCH_CODE    TERR        PC1  
    A1       MENS_10  0.8629186  
    A3       MENS_10 -0.2703238 
    B1       MENS_10  0.9516067  
    B2       MENS_10 -0.1722446
```

resulting data frame:

```
PATCH        CODE    TERR        PC1  
   A            1     MENS_10     0.8629186  
   A            3     MENS_10    -0.2703238 
   B            1     MENS_10     0.9516067  
   B            2     MENS_10    -0.1722446
```

I have seen examples of how to accomplish this when the column to be split has an identifiable text delimiter such as a comma by using `colsplit` in `reshape` but I have failed to find a solution for a structure like mine. Is this possible?

output of str(data)

```
'data.frame':   240 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ PATCH_CODE: Factor w/ 42 levels "A","A1","A2",..: 2 3 4 7 8 12 13 16 17 18 ...
 $ TERR      : Factor w/ 19 levels "MENS_10","MENS_14",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PC1       : num  0.548 1.228 0.273 5.548 3.853 ...
```

Comment: Is your "PATCH_CODE" always 2 characters? If so `do.call(rbind,strsplit(data$PATCH_CODE,""))` would work to split into two columns.

Comment: HMMM, not always 2 letters. There are occasional cases in which it is just a single letter in which case I need the non-existent number to become a 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strsplit`. Passing an empty string as a delimiter results in a split at each letter.

```
a <- c("A1", "B1", "C2", "D5", "R3")
strsplit(a, "")


[[1]]
[1] "A" "1"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "1"

[[3]]
[1] "C" "2"

[[4]]
[1] "D" "5"

[[5]]
[1] "R" "3"
```

If you want to put that in a matrix

```
> do.call(rbind, strsplit(a, ""))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "1" 
[2,] "B"  "1" 
[3,] "C"  "2" 
[4,] "D"  "5" 
[5,] "R"  "3"
```

Comment: I get a non-character argument presumable because not all of my PATCH_CODE columns have exactly 2 characters? I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Probably your code is a `factor`. Cast it to charachter using `as.character` or use `stringAsFactors=F` when reading in the data. The code would also work for 1 letter codes, you'll just get the letter duplicated in the two columns.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of your description, `strsplit` should work fine. If your data are a little more complicated, you can also look at a possible `regex`-based solution.

For this particular example, try:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(mydf$PATCH_CODE, 
                        split = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", 
                        perl = TRUE))
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "1" 
# [2,] "A"  "3" 
# [3,] "B"  "1" 
# [4,] "B"  "2"
```